# Pass all arguments to another function

Tags: php, syntax

I have two functions like this:

```
function mysql_safe_query($format) {
    $args = array_slice(func_get_args(),1);
    $args = array_map('mysql_safe_string',$args);
    $query = vsprintf($format,$args);
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if($result === false) echo '<div class="mysql-error">',mysql_error(),'<br/>',$query,'</div>';
    return $result;
}

function mysql_row_exists() {
    $result = mysql_safe_query(func_get_args());
    return mysql_num_rows($result) > 0;
}
```

The problem is that the second function won't work because it passes the args to the first one as an array, when it expects them as different parameters. Is there any way to get around this, preferably without modifying `mysql_safe_query`?

Comment: Here is the relevant part of the PHP docs: [Variable-length argument lists](https://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

N.B. In PHP 5.6 you can now do this:

```
function mysql_row_exists(...$args) {
    $result = mysql_safe_query(...$args);
    return mysql_num_rows($result) > 0;
}
```

Also, for future readers, mysql_* is deprecated -- don't use those functions.

Answer (score 25):

How about using:

```
$args = func_get_args();
call_user_func_array('mysql_safe_query', $args);
```

Comment: http://uk.php.net/func_get_args says: "Note: Because this function depends on the current scope to determine parameter details, it cannot be used as a function parameter. If this value must be passed, the results should be assigned to a variable, and that variable should be passed."

Comment: perfect!
@volker: doesn't seem to be an issue in this case.

Comment: @volker: err..nevermind. you're right. it didn't complain last time, but now it is. I guess it's better to obey the warnings.

Comment: I am interested to know if there is some syntactic sugar for this as of php 7 (as `...` is somewhat syntactic sugar for  `func_get_args()`)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the situation, following might also work for you and might be a little faster.

```
function  mysql_safe_query($format) {
    $args = func_get_args();
    $args = is_array($args[0]) ? $args[0] : $args; // remove extra container, if needed
    // ...
```

Which now allows for both types of calling, but might be problematic if your **first value** is supposed to be an actual **array**, because it would be unpacked either way.

You could additionally check on the length of your root-array, so it might not be unpacked if if there are other elements, but as mentioned: It is not really that "clean" in general, but might be helpful and fast :-)